# Model Binding vs Form Collection, performance, scalability, change, etc.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I had been working on ASP.NET MVC and I came across various scenarios when Form Collection was used and then I came across some scenarios when Model Binding was used.

Using Model Binding is Good because it maps all the data of requestor from/to. But it adds strong dependency of model on both. Next time whenever I am going to add any input field in View I have to define that in model as well so that it can be processed,then after that I have to handle that in destination when the request is being sent. That can work fine let's assume if my inputs are strongly typed from model.

Now if I define any new input field which is not strongly typed from model, model binder will fail to process it, but FormCollection will work well in any of the cases but we will have to convert all the inputs to specific type that will increase overhead.

Can anyone enlighten which one is better in terms of usability, scalability, performance and relevant to changing requirements?